# Как установить нормальную иконку?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Доброй ночи, друзья! Второй день активно погружаюсь в кодинг, путем различных манипуляций, а также с помощью ChatGPT, создал свое первое приложение под macOS.
Создал приложение с помощью pyinstaller, так как по какой-то причине создать его с помощью py2app не получилось (все время крашилось). Но как мне показалось, pyinstaller даже оказался намного круче (легче). Разобрался с помощью ChatGPT как установить название приложению, имя и так далее, практически сразу понял как установить иконку. Но, дело в том, что отрисовав иконку в фотошопе (размер 512x512) я конвертировал ее в "icns", далее установил ее для моего приложения, но она оказалась намного больше в соотношении с другими иконками приложений на моем макбуке. Как я понимаю, размер в пикселях здесь роли не играет, видимо, это нужно настраивать самостоятельно. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать, в кодинге я полный ноль, поэтому буду очень признателен за подробный ответ! [image: как это выглядит]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.